# How to prevent permission inject on React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I removed READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission from AndroidManifest.xml but during the build this permission is injected
logs:

```
ADDED from /path/to/app/AndroidManifest.xml:13:22-68
uses-permission#android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

i tried to put this line in AndroidManifest.xml but don't work to me.
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />`

How to prevent or remove this permission ?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it? It will not harm.